# Why does GAE BlobstoreService#createUploadUrl(String) include the request query parameter

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I am using the GAE Blobstore with Jersey REST on ther server side. I send a GET request to the server via Android and include a query parameter called `logindx`. My server side code snippet looks like this:

```
@Path("/getuploadurl")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response getUploadUrl(@QueryParam("logindx") Long logIndx )  {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    String uurl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/logblobkey"); 
    logger.severe("urltest: " + uurl);

    return Response.ok(uurl).build();
}
```

The problem is that the result String I get back at Android (and which is also logged) is:

```
urltest: http://bardroid123.appspot.com/_ah/upload/?logindx=-43803902306520/AMmfu6b2Ubvf17gD_5uheZeDhTIsr8nm582oaNi0_SDPWfuxqHmYgtkWqVVP52QbBwnnNbWyJf_lDdf9GDmFKtdHU_eUn5gjjtrOSAB32HSu3HiVgLovO5pYeYDkapBPfu7uuo460Ez0/ALBNUaYAAAAAUeuzYniVLlTqyYCjIkfK7-n0ARv5yoo1/
```

The part `?logindx=-43803902306520/` in the above upload URL should surely not be there? Ho does the `createUploadUrl` function even know how to get hold of the `HttpRequest` object to extract the query parameter?

The problem is when I try to use the above uri in my android app like so:

```
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(uri);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 253: http://bardroid123.appspot.com/_ah/upload/?logindx=-43803902306520/AMmfu6ZDQr7WenGd0N3ZkbI3zfSl0xPcY56XS5p_VQiS_MWxtTwtc1xm8NbhdrhK-PxopCIolsWci_06DQ3EsUJXSlbiavtJKX9JXT7RU3vTnwj-H0yY5DZKv9hbYR0brfOezaVwob1k/ALBNUaYAAAAAUevBZWOmVC0m1tipSR7Lk9WcwePsXBzf/
```

Even more confusing is that I don't get the `?logindx=-43803902306520/` part when I do the get request on my local server (from Eclipse provided by App Engine):

```
http://localhost:8888/res/logs/getuploadurl?logindx=1234567.
```

In that case the browser returns something like:

```
http://localhost:8888/_ah/upload/agtiYXJkcm9pZDEyM3IbCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGDIM
```

Clearly it has got nothing to do with Android and I can't see how this can be Jersey specific either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks - from Africa.

EDIT:

I got it right now by simply dropping the last slash (/) in the uri and the `Illegal character in query` error went away. The uri was working perfectly with the Blobstore with the `?logindx=-43803902306520/` part included. Don't matter now, but still wondering why it is included in the upload uri?